# detail information in development mode asp.net core

Tags: c#, asp.net-core-mvc, asp.net-core-2.0

I try to use Microsoft Graph API in my web. Everything looks like working well on my pc but when my teammate clones the project into her computer, there shows "An error occurred while processing your request." and let us open development mode to see more information.

[error message fig](https://i.stack.imgur.com/OaXKT.png)

We did what it said adding the environment variable. But we still cannot figure out how to obtain the error and what is the error.

Comment: In the configure services method. Add app.UseDeveloperExceptionPage()

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your `startup.cs` you should see a function named `Configure`:

```
public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app, IHostingEnvironment env)
```

In this function, you need to wire up the Developer Exception Page:

```
if (env.IsDevelopment())
{
    app.UseDeveloperExceptionPage();
}
else
{
    app.UseExceptionHandler("/Home/Error");
}
```

Answer (score 0):

in dotnet 6 in program.cs after initialize builder; you can use this code

```
var app = builder.Build();

// Configure the HTTP request pipeline.
if (app.Environment.IsDevelopment())
{
    //Develop Mode
}
else
{
    //Live Mode
}
```